# tsql: can "returning select" come before "update"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a t-sql stored procedure (aka sproc) which selects 3 columns from 'MyTable'.  In addition, I want to update the table in the same sproc:

1. I select the third value from the table.
2. If it equals 'true', I want to update the relevant record in the table to 'false'

I wasn't sure what syntax should I use. Could you help me out?

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[My_PROC]
    @ID varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @Col3 bit;

    set @Col3 = select Col3
    from dbo.MyTable  with (nolock)
    where @ID = ID


    if @Col3 = 'true'  
        update dbo.dbo.MyTable set col3 = 'false'
        where @ID = ID

    select Col1, 
    Col2, 
    Col3
    from dbo.MyTable table  with (nolock) where @ID = ID,
    table.Col1,
    table.Col2,
    @Col3   
END
```

edit: I want to return the **original Col3** (not the updated value).

Comment: "user-procedure (aka usp)" is not common terminology - stored procedures (AKA "sprocs")are not typically differentiated between user & system.  System owned sprocs exist, but because you don't have access to change them the distinction is moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[My_PROC]
    @ID varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT t.col1, 
           t.col2, 
           t.col3
      FROM dbo.MyTable AS t WITH (NOLOCK)
     WHERE t.id = @ID

    -- No need for an IF statement to determine updating...
    UPDATE dbo.dbo.MyTable 
       SET col3 = 'false'
     WHERE id = @ID
       AND t.col3 = 'true'

END
```

I don't know what you're intending for the final `SELECT`, but I can update it once I understand what you intended.

Comment: Thanks.  I want to return the original Col3 (not the updated value).

Comment: @Elad Benda: Then reverse the order of the queries.  Updated the answer to suit, though that was certainly not apparent or mentioned originally.

Comment: Thanks. Just for curiosity: how can i select some values from table and some from sql variables? (I understand my question wasn't clear - I guess I should have repeat it not just in the title)

Comment: @Elad Benda: Post a new question, and provide psuedo-code or as much TSQL as possible.

Comment: But this question has the needed tsql : I set a variable '@Col3' and then want to retrieve it. My select gets Col1, Col2 and '@col3'. I understand you bypassed it as I should have, but I want to learn how to do it in general

Comment: Post a new question. We do one question per question on [so]. Copy the SQL form this one and include a link to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use an OUTPUT clause to output the original value if it was actually updated by the query. OUTPUT won’t give you the original value if the row is not updated by the query, however.

```
    declare @t table (
      ID int,
      tf bit
    );

    insert into @t values
      (1,0),
      (2,1),
      (3,0);

    declare @ID int = 2;

    select * from @t

    update @t set
      tf = 0
    output deleted.ID, deleted.tf
    where ID = @ID;

    select * from @t;
```